# JavaH failing to create C header file for JNI class

Tags: java, c++, class, java-native-interface, jna

This is really baffling me as I have tried everything possible with regards to classpath and various other things. I have tried from various different commands prompts in windows, linux and IDEs but nothing seems to help. Always the same error. Any insight would help here.

I am getting the following error when trying to run javah with the following command:

```
javah -jni -cp jna-3.0.9.jar:java.nio.*:java.util.* CameraInterfaceLibrary
Error: Could not find class file for 'CameraInterfaceLibrary'.
```

I really am stuck here. I just can not figure out why it refuses to generate the header file. No matter what I do it consistently says it can't find the class file. I am just confused. I have tried much simpler examples but with real code it refuses to work.

The code is as follows:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
/**
 * JNA Wrapper for library <b>CameraInterface</b><br>
 * This file was autogenerated by <a href="http://jnaerator.googlecode.com/">JNAerator</a>,<br>
 * a tool written by <a href="http://ochafik.com/">Olivier Chafik</a> that <a href="http://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/wiki/CreditsAndLicense">uses a few opensource projects.</a>.<br>
 * For help, please visit <a href="http://nativelibs4java.googlecode.com/">NativeLibs4Java</a> , <a href="http://rococoa.dev.java.net/">Rococoa</a>, or <a href="http://jna.dev.java.net/">JNA</a>.
 */
public class CameraInterfaceLibrary implements StdCallLibrary {
    public static final String JNA_LIBRARY_NAME = "CameraInterface";
    public static final NativeLibrary JNA_NATIVE_LIB = NativeLibrary.getInstance(CameraInterfaceLibrary.JNA_LIBRARY_NAME);
    static {
        Native.loadLibrary(CameraInterfaceLibrary.JNA_LIBRARY_NAME, CameraInterfaceLibrary.class);
    }
    public static class DV_TM extends Structure {
        /**
         * Second.interval is [0.59] * /<br>
         * int tm_min; /* To the value interval [0.59]
         */
        public int tm_sec;
        /** Value seconds interval [0.23] */
        public int tm_hour;
        /** The value date of the month interval [1.31] */
        public int tm_mday;
        /** The value date of the month interval [1.31] */
        public int tm_mon;
        /** Month (from the beginning of January, o behalf of the month) value interval [0.11] */
        public int tm_year;
        /** Year, its value is equal to the actual year as 2010 */
        public int tm_wday;
        /** The value range for the week [0.6], where O stands for Sunday, 1 for Monday, and so on */
        public int tm_yday;
        /** Number of days from the beginning of January 1 each year ranging from [0.365], where 0 represents January 1, 1 represents January 2, and so on, can be set to 0 */
        public int tm_isdst;
        public DV_TM() {
            super();
        }
        protected List<? > getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("tm_sec", "tm_hour", "tm_mday", "tm_mon", "tm_year", "tm_wday", "tm_yday", "tm_isdst");
        }
        /**
         * @param tm_sec Second.interval is [0.59] * /<br>
         * int tm_min; /* To the value interval [0.59]<br>
         * @param tm_hour Value seconds interval [0.23]<br>
         * @param tm_mday The value date of the month interval [1.31]<br>
         * @param tm_mon The value date of the month interval [1.31]<br>
         * @param tm_year Month (from the beginning of January, o behalf of the month) value interval [0.11]<br>
         * @param tm_wday Year, its value is equal to the actual year as 2010<br>
         * @param tm_yday The value range for the week [0.6], where O stands for Sunday, 1 for Monday, and so on<br>
         * @param tm_isdst Number of days from the beginning of January 1 each year ranging from [0.365], where 0 represents January 1, 1 represents January 2, and so on, can be set to 0
         */
        public DV_TM(int tm_sec, int tm_hour, int tm_mday, int tm_mon, int tm_year, int tm_wday, int tm_yday, int tm_isdst) {
            super();
            this.tm_sec = tm_sec;
            this.tm_hour = tm_hour;
            this.tm_mday = tm_mday;
            this.tm_mon = tm_mon;
            this.tm_year = tm_year;
            this.tm_wday = tm_wday;
            this.tm_yday = tm_yday;
            this.tm_isdst = tm_isdst;
        }

        /* JR - Removed as no deemed necessary at this point
        public DV_TM(com.sun.jna.Pointer peer) {
            super(peer);
        }*/

        public static class ByReference extends DV_TM implements Structure.ByReference {

        };
        public static class ByValue extends DV_TM implements Structure.ByValue {

        };
    };
    /**
     * Connected devices (connect with camera)<br>
     * Original signature : <code>int CConnectDV()</code><br>
     * <i>native declaration : line 18</i>
     */
    public static native int CConnectDV();
    /**
     * Disconnect the device (disconnect with camera)<br>
     * Original signature : <code>int CDisconnectDV()</code><br>
     * <i>native declaration : line 20</i>
     */
    public static native int CDisconnectDV();
    /**
     * Landing equipment parameters: password (connect and open the camera parameter: password)<br>
     * Original signature : <code>int CLogin(char*)</code><br>
     * <i>native declaration : line 22</i><br>
     * @deprecated use the safer methods {@link #CLogin(java.nio.ByteBuffer)} and {@link #CLogin(com.sun.jna.Pointer)} instead
     */
    public static native int CLogin(com.sun.jna.Pointer Password);
    /**
     * Landing equipment parameters: password (connect and open the camera parameter: password)<br>
     * Original signature : <code>int CLogin(char*)</code><br>
     * <i>native declaration : line 22</i>
     */
    public static native int CLogin(ByteBuffer Password);
    /**
     * The school parameters: see DV-TM structure (timing parameter: look at the DV-TM structure)<br>
     * Original signature : <code>int CSetTime(DV_TM*)</code><br>
     * <i>native declaration : line 24</i>
     */
    public static native int CSetTime(CameraInterfaceLibrary.DV_TM ptm);
    /**
     * Read machine time parameters: see DV-TM structure (read the machine time parameter: look at the DV-TM structure)<br>
     * Original signature : <code>int CGetTime(DV_TM*)</code><br>
     * <i>native declaration : line 26</i>
     */
    public static native int CGetTime(CameraInterfaceLibrary.DV_TM ptm);
    /**
     * Set password parameters: password new password 6 (set password parameter: password 6 new password)<br>
     * Original signature : <code>int CSetPassword(char*)</code><br>
     * <i>native declaration : line 28</i><br>
     * @deprecated use the safer methods {@link #CSetPassword(java.nio.ByteBuffer)} and {@link #CSetPassword(com.sun.jna.Pointer)} instead
     */
    public static native int CSetPassword(com.sun.jna.Pointer Password);
    /**
     * Set password parameters: password new password 6 (set password parameter: password 6 new password)<br>
     * Original signature : <code>int CSetPassword(char*)</code><br>
     * <i>native declaration : line 28</i>
     */
    public static native int CSetPassword(ByteBuffer Password);
    /**
     * Set the number parameter: ID Number 13 (set ID number parameter: 13 ID number)<br>
     * Original signature : <code>int CSetID(char*)</code><br>
     * <i>native declaration : line 30</i><br>
     * @deprecated use the safer methods {@link #CSetID(java.nio.ByteBuffer)} and {@link #CSetID(com.sun.jna.Pointer)} instead
     */
    public static native int CSetID(com.sun.jna.Pointer ID);
    /**
     * Set the number parameter: ID Number 13 (set ID number parameter: 13 ID number)<br>
     * Original signature : <code>int CSetID(char*)</code><br>
     * <i>native declaration : line 30</i>
     */
    public static native int CSetID(ByteBuffer ID);
    /**
     * Read the number parameter: ID Number 13 (read ID number parameter: 13 ID number)<br>
     * Original signature : <code>int CGetID(char*)</code><br>
     * <i>native declaration : line 32</i><br>
     * @deprecated use the safer methods {@link #CGetID(java.nio.ByteBuffer)} and {@link #CGetID(com.sun.jna.Pointer)} instead
     */
    public static native int CGetID(com.sun.jna.Pointer ID);
    /**
     * Read the number parameter: ID Number 13 (read ID number parameter: 13 ID number)<br>
     * Original signature : <code>int CGetID(char*)</code><br>
     * <i>native declaration : line 32</i>
     */
    public static native int CGetID(ByteBuffer ID);
    /**
     * Enter the U disk mode (Enter the U disk mode)<br>
     * Original signature : <code>int CIntoUDiskMode()</code><br>
     * <i>native declaration : line 34</i>
     */
    public static native int CIntoUDiskMode();
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to generate a C header file for a JNA mapping class?  You don't need to do that, the JNA direct mapping is ready to run as soon as you compile it, not native implementation required.

Comment: Maybe I have missed the point here but JNA is meant to replace Jni,  no?  So you still need to generate header files to interface with the C/C++ code that you intend to interface with hence the references to the stdcall methods and c pointers or am I missing something completely? How else would I interface with the C/C++ without a header for the Java code?

Comment: If you're replacing JNI you don't need to go through any of the JNI steps or write any JNI C code. Otherwise JNA would be pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use JNA, there is no longer any need to generate C headers nor compile any native code.

When using direct mapping, methods declared `native` are automatically bound to their corresponding methods in the target shared library.

JNA uses the method signatures and `StdCall` tagging interfaces to figure out how to translate your Java call into a native call with the appropriate type conversions.

**EDIT**

Make sure you call `Native.register()` in your static initializer, rather than `Native.loadLibrary()`.  Please add a note to your question if you've achieved a working model.

You can test execution by writing a simple `main` function which calls one or more of your methods.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed this.

That actually clears it up as to why the header is not needed. So I can compile my code and just load via the standard System.loadLibrary() method?

Comment: You don't even need `System.loadLibrary()`.  JNA takes care of that under the covers when your direct-mapped class's static initializer runs.

Comment: I was using JNAerator to create this. It seemed to me like BrigJ was a better choice. What's your opinion on this? I had to make changes to the output created to change Native.register(X, x) to Native. LoadLibrary(X, x). Which isn't ideal. Clearly, I'm not an expert with JNA, BridJ or JNI

Comment: You *need* to use `Native.register()` -- that's what binds the Java `native` methods to their shared library counterparts.  `Native.LoadLibrary()` does *not* do the same thing.  JNAerator output usually needs some fine tuning, because you can't always divine the intent of C declarations from source.  It was originally written to auto-parse header files for JNA, but was later adapted to also generate for BridJ when its talented author started that project.

Comment: I have it all solved with BridJ now. Thanks for the help, you really pointed me in the right direction. The only problem I am having now is with @Library() in BridJ and relative locations. It works perfectly passing it full locations but relative locations fail it. But that is another issue. Once again thanks for all your help. You really pointed me in the right direction! I have it fully working now, except for that minor problem of having an absolute location.

Answer (score 3):

Other folks are correct (you don't need javah if you are using JPA).

But for thoroughness (and to help you with other things that you'll probably run into with Java development), I suspect the answer to your question is that you aren't specifying the classpath properly.

Here are the docs for javah: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javah.html

The problems that I see with your command line:

1. The appropriate argument is -classpath (not -cp)
2. You need to separate your entries using semicolon, not colon
3. You must specify the path of the root of your classes (if that happens to be the current directory, you still have to include it using '.')
4. You must specify the path of dependent jar files
5. Under no circumstances would adding import-like identifiers to the classpath make sense (i.e. java.nio.* is an import - that has no relevance here)
6. If you have your class in a package (which you should!), then you need to include that in the classname

In a normal project (where classes and dependent jars are stored in separate folders), I would use something like this:

```
javah -jni -classpath C:\MyApp\Classes;C:\MyApp\lib\* com.myapp.MyAppLibrary
```

Note the use of the wildcard to load all jar files in the lib\ folder.

Comment: VG It's also possible, indeed probable, that he omitted the package name on the class name.

Comment: @KevinDay, great answer but it seems it doesn't actually explain what I was doing wrong. I had missed the point of JNA it seems. Header files are not required. I have the same option with BrigJ (which seems much cleaner than JNA).

Comment: @JamieReid Come off it. He lists six different things you could have been doing wrong. You didn't provide enough information to decide between them.